# React, Node, Mongodb : My image file is not being served from backend and trying to render it on the React side throws 404 not found

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, multer

I am uploading the image from React front end.

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            uploadRecipesFormData: {},
            selectedFile: null,
            redirect : null,
        };
    }

    uploadRecipe = () => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', this.state.selectedFile, this.state.selectedFile.name);
        for(const key in this.state.uploadRecipesFormData){
            formData.append(key, this.state.uploadRecipesFormData[key]);
        }
        axios.post(`http://localhost:3000/recipes`, formData, {})
             .then(res =>  {
                 alert(res.data);
                 this.setState({
                     redirect: "/uploaded-recipes"
                 });
             })
             .catch(err => console.error(err));
    }

    onChangeImageHandler = e => {
        this.setState({
            selectedFile: e.target.files[0]
        });
    }

    handleChange = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.handleInputChange(e.target.name, e.target.value);
    }

    handleInputChange = (key, value) => {

        this.setState({
            uploadRecipesFormData: {
                _id: uuidv4(),
                ...this.state.uploadRecipesFormData,
                addedBy: 'guest',
                [key]: value
            }
        });
    }

    submitRecipe = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.uploadRecipe();
    }
```

On backend Im receiving the image along with other form data:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'public/images')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, `${file.originalname} `)
    }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('file');

/*
Endpoint: /recipes
Outcome: Add recipe 
*/ 
router.post('/', (req, res) => {

    upload(req,res, err => {
        if(err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
            return res.status(500).json(err);
        }
        else if(err) {
            return res.status(500).json(err);
        }
        console.log(req.file.filename);
        console.log(req.body);

            const newRecipeData = new Recipe({
                _id: req.body._id,
                name: req.body.name,
                ingredients: req.body.ingredients.split(','),
                instructions: req.body.instructions,
                cuisine: req.body.cuisine || '',
                image: `http://localhost:3000/images/${req.file.filename}` || '',
                addedBy: req.body.addedBy || ''
        });

          newRecipeData.save()
                     .then(result => {
                         res.status(201).send('Recipe added successfully!');
                     })
                     .catch(err => console.log(err));
    });
});
```

The data is being stored in MongoDb with path to public directory to image. However, this file is being stored as a binary file instead of an image file. 
I have enabled express static in my app.js:

```
    app.use(express.static('public'));
```

I am able to see the file in public/images folder but its a binary file due to which when I try to access it from my react front end it throws 404 error. I then manually tried adding an actual image to public/images folder and the it worked. How could I preserve the file type while receiving file data from front end ? Answers online are not clear to me of what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems okay, however, I can spot a little bug in this block of code that might be causing the error:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'public/images')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, `${file.originalname} `)
    }
});
```

There is an extra space after `${file.originalname}` in this 
`` cb(null, `${file.originalname} `) `` statement. That extra space would change the file name, consequently, it appears as binary and you can't access it from the front end. Try removing that space and see if it works.

Comment: That was it! You saved my day. Thanks so much